# Django ORM group by on primary key mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

In the django ORM it's easy to group by when using an aggregate function like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.values('id').annotate(Count('id'))
```

However if I want to group by *without* an aggregation function (in case of a join for example)

```
User.objects.filter(groups__name='foo')
```

You can use `distinct` function, but it will distinct *on all* columns. Which is painfully slow.

In some other DB you can do `DISTINCT ON` but not on mariadb/mysql.

Is there a way to group by a specific column with the django ORM or do I have to write RawSQL ?

Comment: Normally it will not be slow, it will see that the `id` is the primary key, and that all columns are functionally dependent, hence `DISTINCT` will not raise an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Normally [**`.distinct()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) will not be slow, it will see that the `id` is the primary key, and that all columns are functionally dependent, hence `DISTINCT` will not raise an issue. So the most straight forward way is:

```
User.objects.filter(groups__name='foo').distinct()
```

You can use a `GROUP BY`, for example with:

```
User.objects.filter(groups__name='foo').annotate(ngroup=Count('groups'))
```

but will that help? A `GROUP BY` is an implicit `DISTINCT`: it will make groups of users. This thus means that it will somehow have to store the group with as label the thing with which you group by, so here the `id` of the `User`, but it also has to do all logic to create aggregates for these groups. For `DISTINCT` if a second row with the same data will be used, it can immediately discard that row.

So likely the `.distinct()` will outperform the `GROUP BY`, at least of the data set is quite massive, and the number of related groups is also not zero, one or two per user.

Comment: On MySQL, `SELECT DISTINCT` will try to distinct on all column.

With row SQL, I have 3x faster query when using group by on the pk than using `distinct`.

Comment: @RémiDesgrange: well I've tested this on some databases, and the GROUP BY took 403ms on a database with 230k rows, and 398ms for the same table with `DISTINCT *`. Evidently that can depend on the MySQL. My experience is that MySQL does not do much to optimize queries, for example subqueries that have a constant result rerun *per* row.